# Take random photos with PHP

Tags: php

I am building an examination system. I was wondering, could I take random photos of the person taking the exam in random intervals? The students will be required to allow the site to use the camera for them to access the question. The system will then take random photos in random intervals. I want to use PHP or anyone with an idea how I can go about it?

Comment: PHP is a server-side language. Unless your server is in front of the user and ready to take photos, I would suggest you look at a client-side language like Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is more suited for that kind of task. Check out [this API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/B2G_OS/API/Camera_API/Introduction) for more informations ¸
Edit, You should take in consideration that not alot of browsers allows it. it seams to be more accepted in mobile browser.
Hopes it helps !

- Nic

Comment: that's a good link but I have to mention that link only answers are considered as being of low-quality and should contain essentials parts of code required

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the feedback, i will take it in consideration for my next interventions.

Comment: you're welcome Nicolas. You can still edit your answer to contain the code. Someone may flag it as low-quality, just trying to help you out ;-)